# How to send an object from an object to another object?

Tags: javascript

I have a list which has some cities and has an empty object at the start. I need to set my empty object named best cities to an object which contains madrid like below. it should hold madrid key too in inside. I've tried to bestCity=cities.madrid but I lost the madrid key with this method. I wonder how to make this. Thank you.

```
cities: {
  madrid: {
    sunny: "yes",
    capital: "yes" 
  },
  london: {
    sunny: "no",
    capital: "yes"
  },
  miami: {
    sunny: "yes",
    capital: "no"
  },
  hamburg: {
    sunny: "no",
    capital: "no",
  }
}
```

empty object at the start:

```
bestCity: {}
```

best city should be as below.

```
bestCity: {
  madrid: {
    sunny: "yes",
    capital: "yes"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use destructuring `{bestCity : {...cities.madrid}}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `destructuring` to extract `madrid` then creat an object with it :

```js
const cities = {
  madrid: {
    sunny: "yes",
    capital: "yes" 
  },
  london: {
    sunny: "no",
    capital: "yes"
  },
  miami: {
    sunny: "yes",
    capital: "no"
  },
  hamburg: {
    sunny: "no",
    capital: "no",
  }
}

const { madrid } = cities ;

const bestCity = { madrid };

console.log( bestCity );
```

Comment: This was the exactly what I want to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Assuming you actually wanted to choose a good city instead of just copying a hardcoded one

```js
const cities = { 
  madrid:  { sunny: "yes", capital: "yes" },
  london:  { sunny: "no",  capital: "yes" },
  miami:   { sunny: "yes", capital: "no"  },
  hamburg: { sunny: "no",  capital: "no", }
}

let bestCity = {};
Object.keys(cities).forEach(k => {
  const city = cities[k];
  if (city.sunny === "yes" && city.capital === "yes") bestCity[k]=city;
})
console.log(bestCity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cities.madrid` to access the `madrid` object inside `cities`. Then, you can assign a certain variable / object value to it like so:

```
bestCities = {}
bestCities.madrid = cities.madrid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bestCity.madrid = cities.madrid;
```